# LM2576 output voltage error

Tags: voltage

In my [earlier post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251813/sim900-circuit-stops-working-after-30-40secs?noredirect=1#comment556510_251813), I was using LM317 for SIM900 but due to some voltage drop problem, I decided to go with LM2576. I am trying to step down the voltage from 12v to 4.5v using [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf). I have studied the voltage calculation formula described on page 21. For the time being, I am just testing it on breadboard so have not connected the capacitors and diode at the output. Following is the schematic

[image]

According to the voltage calculation formula:

```
O/P Volts = Vref(1 + R2/R1)
O/P Volts = 1.23(1 + 4700/2000)
O/P Volts = 1.23(1 + 2.35)
O/P Volts = 4.12v
```

So the calculation shows output voltage of 4.12v but in practical it is showing 5.64v.

Is my calculation wrong or I am doing something wrong in the circuit. Please help.?

Comment: Usually these switchers have a minimal load requirement. What is your load, and what is that requirement?

Comment: @PlasmaHH  I will be using this output volts for powering SIM900 at 4.5 volts 2amps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am just testing it on breadboard so have not connected the
>   capacitors and diode at the output.

That's just plain ignorance. All bets are off if you don't have the flyback diode because it **IS** an integral part of the energy reclamation into the output capacitor (also not fitted) from the inductor.

The diode also prevents (as a side issue) back emfs from the inductor harming the chip.

The other issue is that without the output capacitor the voltage across the potential divider will be a somewhat distorted square wave and not representative of anything when measured with a multimeter.

It's like trying to drive a car with the tyres removed.

Answer (score 9):

You **cannot** test this without the diode and the output capacitors. It simply won't work properly as they are a vital part of the circuit, unlike say a 7805. As Plasma says you should also have some reasonable minimum load- a few K should be fine.

They are also difficult to test reliably on a breadboard, you need to minimize the loop areas containing the diode, inductor, output capacitor and chip to GND/0V and C1.